# Standard way to send data to running python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, daemon

I have a "server" python script which has a `while True` loop which watches a text file and processes the data in the file whenever it is updated.

I'd like to be able to send the text data to the script directly without using a file as a go-between.

What is the conventional way of doing this? Are Python sockets the way to go? This is a small project and I do not forsee the need to asynchronously handle incoming data.

Comment: Yeah if you want to periodically send data to the server, then a socket is probably your best bet, unless you wanted to setup a web server & POST the data to some endpoint

Comment: Or use a [FIFO](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html)

Comment: There is no "standard way to send data" to a program written in Python or any other language. There are a large number of options. Which one is best depends on your requirements. For exchanging simple blobs of text where the two processes are running on the same system a named FIFO is probably the simplest solution. Using a socket makes it easy to run the two processes on different systems. Beyond that you have to decide how to encode the data if it isn't a simple blob of text with a easily identified terminator; e.g., a newline.